# Почему при возникновении ошибки не выполняется код до строки с ошибкой?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Намеренно пытаюсь изменить значение `notice_period_in_days`, чтобы посмотреть, какую ошибку получу.

Вот PL/SQL код:

```
set serveroutput on;

declare 
    notice_period_in_days CONSTANT NUMBER := 60;
begin 
    dbms_output.put_line (notice_period_in_days);
    notice_period_in_days := 50;
    dbms_output.put_line (notice_period_in_days);
end;
```

Это вызывает, как и ожидалось, ошибку:

> PLS-00363: expression 'NOTICE_PERIOD_IN_DAYS' cannot be used as an assignment target

Но почему первая строка вывода `dbms_output.put_line` не выполняется? Ожидаю ошибку только в той строке, где присваивается новое значение для `notice_period_in_days`.

Как можно это объяснить?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [What happens if I edit a constant value in PL SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65579380) от участника [@Surender Raja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3240790/surender-raja)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65579380

Answer (score 4):

После отправки блока на сервер БД, он сначала компилируется в выполняемый интерпретатором PL/SQL байт-код, и только если никаких ошибок при этом не возникнет, блок будет запущен на выполнение.

Если посмотреть полное сообщение об ошибке:

```
SQL> declare n constant int := 0;
  2  begin n := 10;
  3  end;
  4  /
begin n := 10;
      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PLS-00363: expression 'N' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

, то первая строка ошибки:

```
$ oerr ora 6550
06550, 00000, "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
// *Cause:  Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

говорит, что произоша ошибка компиляции. То есть, *блок вообще не был запущен на выполнение*.